# Differences in behavior of kill(pid, SIGINT) between Debian and Red Hat based distros

Tags: c++, debian, posix, redhat, sigint

I'm encountering a discrepancy in the behavior of my code when using `kill(pid, SIGINT)` between Debian 12 and CentOS 7 in a virtual machine. Previously, this code worked as expected in Fedora 39.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

void sigint_handler(int signal) {
    cout << "The child process received the SIGINT signal. Ending..." << endl;
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main() {
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        cerr << "Error creating the child process." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // Child process
        cout << "Child process created. PID: " << getpid() << endl;
        
        // Signal handler for SIGINT
        signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);

        // Executing ping for 10 iterations, although parent process should stop it earlier
        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "ping -c 10 google.com", NULL);
    } else {
        // Parent process
        cout << "parent process. PID from child: " << pid << endl;
        sleep(3); // Wait 3 seconds before sending the SIGINT

        cout << "Sending SIGINT to the child process..." << endl;
        if (kill(pid, SIGINT) == -1) {
            cerr << "Error sending SIGINT to the child process." << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0); // Wait to the child process to end
        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            cout << "Child process end with status: " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Child process end in an incorrect way" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After migrating to Debian 12, the code snippet above doesn't behave as expected. Instead of stopping the ping process after sending the SIGINT signal, it continues executing all 10 iterations. However, when running the same code in a CentOS VM, it behaves correctly, stopping after a few iterations.

Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Additional information:

g++ version in Debian 12: g++ (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0

g++ version in CentOS 7 VM: g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)

Edit 1:

I have also tried with `system("ping -c 10 google.com")` instead of `execl()` without success. Same with `sigaction()` and it doesn't work.

In addition to that, the problem isn't related to the different implementations of `ping` in Debian and Red Hat based distros, because I have tried with my original code and it doesn't stop.

In my original code, instead of `ping`, I call a `program.o` that has a infinite loop that should be stopped with `Ctrl+C`. In Fedora and CentOS my program runs perfectly while in Debian it doesn't.

Comment: *this code worked as expected* What was expected? We don't know your expectation.

Comment: `kill()` is not of C++ standard. It's POSIX.

Comment: The `signal` function traditionally have had different semantics on different Unix systems. It's recommended to use [`sigaction`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead,

Comment: `sigint_handler` can only do a very limited set of operations.  I/O is not one of them.  Check out the **man** page for details.

Answer (score 2):

This does not work as it seems you expect:

```
// Signal handler for SIGINT
signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);

// Executing ping for 10 iterations, although parent process should stop it earlier
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "ping -c 10 google.com", NULL);
```

`execl` will [reset the signal action back to the default](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) in the new process. This is setting the signal handler to `sigint_handler` only for an extremely short window.

Therefore, how `ping` reacts to `SIGINT` is completely dependent on how it sets up its signal handlers. Presumably, the different VMs have different implementations or versions of `ping`. `iputils` and `inetutils` both have a `ping`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue looking at the processes launched using `pgrep -l -u $USER`.

If we consider that the binary of the program is called `program` and `PID from child: 10001`, in CentOS we have this:

```
$ pgrep -l -u $USER
10000 program
10001 ping
```

While in Debian we have this:

```
$ pgrep -l -u $USER
10000 program
10001 sh
10002 ping
```

That means that in Debian, in order to make the program work just like in CentOS, we should change the `pid` to `pid + 1` because of that `sh` process with ID 10001 in the middle.

The only thing that would be useful to know is why in Debian that `sh` process
is created while in CentOS is not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends the way the shell constructs the tree of (sub)processes when interpreting commands. It is possible that `/bin/sh` is not the same shell on different Linux distributions.

Anyway, why do you launch `ping` under control of shell and not launching it directly?

```
execlp("ping","ping","-c","10","google.com",NULL);
```

More: you may not use `SIGINT` whose semantic for shells may also differs greatly (some may just wait for sub command to terminate). Prefer the use of `SIGTERM`.

Also note that `exec`-ing reset signal handlers to default behaviour if sets the a catching function before, and prefer the use of `sigaction` which have reliable behaviour (it is not the case fo `signal`).

Comment: Yes, that's true.
Actually, the `ping` was only to demonstrate my problem. But now with execlp works fine in Debian.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user23642012 also look at my edit about the use of `SIGINT`.